# Nginx - Force HTTPS only on main domain, and HTTP on all subdomains

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, https, subdomain

I have had a developer trying to create the SSL config for my Nginx server, but it still doesn't work the way it should.
I want to force/redirect all my subdomains to HTTP, and only let the main domain with no subdomain, with SSL.

This is my current config:

```
set $ssl_rule "";
if ($scheme = http) {
set $ssl_rule "1";
}
if ($scheme = https) {
    set $ssl_rule "0";
}

if ($host = "mystite.com") {
set $ssl_rule "${ssl_rule}1";
}
if ($host = "www.mysite.com") {
    set $ssl_rule "${ssl_rule}1";
}

if ($host ~ (?!www).+.mysite\.com) {
 set $ssl_rule "${ssl_rule}0";
}
if ($ssl_rule = "11") {
 return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
#if ($ssl_rule = "00") {
#         return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
#}
```

Can anybody see what's wrong with my config?

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is "if" with a bunch of domains under one server rather than defining domains under separate servers. Here's how you should do it.

```
# Main domain. Can swap to www if you like.
server {
   server_name example.com;
   listen 443 ssl http2;
   ssl_certificate /var/lib/acme/live/etc;
   ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/acme/live/etc;

   location {
     // whatever
   }
}

# Forward https www to root domain
server {
   server_name www.example.com;
   listen 443 ssl https;
   ssl_certificate /var/lib/acme/live/etc;
   ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/acme/live/etc;

   location / {
     return 301 https://example.com;
   }
}

# Forward www and non-www http to main https
server {
   server_name www.example.com example.com;
   listen 80;

   location / {
     return 301 https://example.com;
   }
}

# First http subdomain
server {
   server_name subdomain2.example.com;
   listen 80;

   location / {
     // whatever
   }
}

# second http subdomain
server {
   server_name subdomain2.example.com;
   listen 80;

   location / {
     // whatever
   }
}
```